# Wordpres - redirect my templates 404.php page to https using htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

On normal links on my wordpress site user always gets https. However, when user types in some page that does not exist, my site can use both http and https.

For example:

Visitor types in mypage.com/non-existing-page, and he gets the 404.php page template, but the 404.php page template can be visited via http and as well via https.

What i want to do is to redirect the http://mypage.com/non-existing-page to https://mypage.com/non-existing-page.

My htaccess file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last rules in your .htaccess are redirecting non-HTTPS traffic to the HTTPS version. I think you need to move the those lines to the top, before the Wordpress rules. Here is the HTTPS-forcing rule that I have used in the past:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: Moved my last rules to the top and works fine. Thank you!